# Java compile error error: ArrayList.add(Object) not applicable for the arguments (float)

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayListDemo 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
        list.add("Praveen");
        list.add(15);
        list.add(4.5F);
        list.add(true);
        list.add(false);
        System.out.println(list);

    }

}
```

Showing error:

```
The method add(Object) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (float)
The method add(Object) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)
The method add(Object) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (float)
```

I am using Java 1.8.
Same example is working on my instructor computer and not showing any error....same post is not answered by any programmer....please help me...

Comment: you are entering integer, float values instead of Integer & Float objects. Arraylist accepts only objects.

Comment: but same program is working on my instructor computer....

Comment: I don't think you're actually using Java 8. You may have the Java 8 JDK installed, but it can compile at any language level - you need to tell Eclipse that it's Java 8.

Comment: Also, generics exist for more than 10 years now. Use them. Don't use raw type. It should be `List<Object> list=new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: How would i tell to eclipse that i am using java......This is snap shot

Comment: i have already set the project properties to java build path-JRE system Libarary(jre 1.8._60)

Comment: @PraveenYadavCSPIET add `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` and see  java version

Comment: any help would be appriciated

Comment: @FastSnail it showing...1.8.0_60 java version

Comment: @PraveenYadavCSPIET after you change java version ? or ?? did you change java version ??so hope it's working without error now?

Comment: @FastSnail....Now Program works after changing compiler compliance level to 1.4 to 1.7.....unchecking the project specific properties thank you sir for your help.....

Answer (score 2):

Your project targets very old Java compiler version. Your code is using auto-boxing which requires at least 1.5.

Go to: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler. Set "Compiler compliance level" to 1.8 (or 1.7 - if not available). Click Ok. 
Right click on your project -> Properties -> Java Compiler. Make sure "Enable project specific settings" is unchecked.
Rebuild your project.

Comment: @ Banthar.....your Solution is works.....thank you so much sir.....

Answer (score 1):

Works for me using Oracle JDK 1.8.

The problem you're having is with [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) - this is a feature which was added in Java 5 which allows the compiler to automatically convert between primitive types and their wrapper objects.

So long as the compiler can autobox those primitives into objects, they'll be added to the list fine.